# Problems with Visual Studio and MySQL(XAMPP)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, winforms

I connected MySql from XAMPP with Visual Studio Project(I think I have connected it), and I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057   Message=Option not
> supported. Arg_ParamName_Name   Source=MySql.Data   StackTrace:    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetOption(String
> key)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String
> keyword, Object value)    at
> System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String
> value)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String
> connectionString)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
> value)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor(String
> connectionString)    at WinFormsApp1.Form1.button1_Click(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) in
> C:\Users\Amar\source\repos\WinFormsApp1\WinFormsApp1\Form1.cs:line 30
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
> button, Int32 clicks)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg,
> IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
> Interop.User32.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.Interop.Mso.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(UIntPtr
> dwComponentID, msoloop uReason, Void* pvLoopData)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(msoloop
> reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(msoloop
> reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)    at
> WinFormsApp1.Program.Main() in
> C:\Users\Amar\source\repos\WinFormsApp1\WinFormsApp1\Program.cs:line
> 22
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetOption(string)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.this[string].set(string,
> object)
> System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString.set(string)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(string)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.ConnectionString.set(string)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.MySqlConnection(string)
> WinFormsApp1.Form1.button1_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
> ...
> [Call Stack Truncated]

Comment: It might not be able to connect to a MySQL DB hence: This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetOption(string)

Comment: `Message=Option not supported` makes me think that one of your connection string options is incorrect. Double-check it for typos and make sure every option and value is spelt correctly. It would also help if you can paste the entire connection string (without password) here.

Comment: The solution was actually to use .NET Framework instead of .NET Core Windows Application. Don't understand why but magically fixed the problem. (My best guess is, Framework is Windows only so it uses dll which I linked without problems, but Core is cross-platform solution and doesn't seem to handle it well)